# Chunk a text based on regex expression with delimiter including

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a long text, about 10k characters that contain many sections. I need to chunk the text based on these sections. Every chunk should contain a section. The text template is represented by sections with titles start with "SECTION|RUBRIQUE n" where n is the number of the section.

This is my try:

```
import re

def get_text_chunks(text):
    section_pattern = r"(SECTION|RUBRIQUE) \d+: .+"
    section_headings = re.findall(section_pattern, text)
    chunks = re.split(section_pattern, text)

    return chunks

long_text = """
This text should be ignored.
RUBRIQUE 1: IDENTIFICATION OF THE SUBSTANCE/MIXTURE AND OF THE COMPANY/UNDERTAKING
1.1. Product identifier
Product name: - SANITARY DEODORIZING DESCALING CLEANER
Product code: DUOBAC SANIT
1.2. Applicable uses of the substance or mixture and uses advised against
SANITARY HYGIENE

RUBRIQUE 2: HAZARDS IDENTIFICATION
2.1. Classification of the substance or mixture
In accordance with Regulation (EC) No. 1272/2008 and its adaptations.
Skin corrosion, Category 1B (Skin Corr. 1B, H31 4).

RUBRIQUE 2: HAZARDS IDENTIFICATION
2.2. Another Classification
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
"""

chunks = get_text_chunks(long_text)
for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
    print("-----------------------")
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
This text should be ignored.
-----------------------
RUBRIQUE 1: IDENTIFICATION OF THE SUBSTANCE/MIXTURE AND OF THE COMPANY/UNDERTAKING
-----------------------
1.1. Product identifier
Product name: - SANITARY DEODORIZING DESCALING CLEANER
Product code: DUOBAC SANIT
1.2. Applicable uses of the substance or mixture and uses advised against
SANITARY HYGIENE
-----------------------
RUBRIQUE 2: HAZARDS IDENTIFICATION
-----------------------
2.1. Classification of the substance or mixture
In accordance with Regulation (EC) No. 1272/2008 and its adaptations.
Skin corrosion, Category 1B (Skin Corr. 1B, H31 4).
-----------------------
```

Instead of having this Output:

```
RUBRIQUE 1: IDENTIFICATION OF THE SUBSTANCE/MIXTURE AND OF THE COMPANY/UNDERTAKING
1.1. Product identifier
Product name: - SANITARY DEODORIZING DESCALING CLEANER
Product code: DUOBAC SANIT
1.2. Applicable uses of the substance or mixture and uses advised against
SANITARY HYGIENE
-----------------------
RUBRIQUE 2: HAZARDS IDENTIFICATION

2.1. Classification of the substance or mixture
In accordance with Regulation (EC) No. 1272/2008 and its adaptations.
Skin corrosion, Category 1B (Skin Corr. 1B, H31 4).
-----------------------
```

PS: my input text does not start with SECTION|RUBRIQUE from the first line. So that first part should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look-ahead so to avoid that the separator has a size. Also, don't use capture groups, as those result in extra elements in the output list:

```
    section_pattern = r"(?=(?:SECTION|RUBRIQUE) \d+: .+)"
    chunks = re.split(section_pattern, text)[1:]
```

With `[1:]` you ignore the text that comes before the first occurrence of the separator.

Comment: @tricot, thank you so mush for your help, do you have any idea how to group sections together, cause the current solution,  return 2 items of "RUBRIQUE 2", They should concatenated into one item.